# How to apply Generics methods

Tags: c#, generics

I'm using **`FileHelper.dll`** for converting **`list`** into **`csv`** files and it is working perfectly.

Totally I'm having **9 Lists** and corresponding **9 methods** to handle file conversion and it will grow in future

Here,I have showed only 3 methods.

```
//-----Transaction.csv
public DateTime ExportResultsToCsv(string filePath, string HeaderLine, List<RetailTransaction> retailTxnList)
   {
      engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(RetailTransaction)) { HeaderText = HeaderLine };
      engine.WriteFile(filePath, retailTxnList);
            return DateTime.Now;
   }

//-----ConcessionSale.csv
public DateTime ExportResultsToCsv(string filePath, string HeaderLine, List<ConcessionSale> concessionSaleList)
    {
      engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(ConcessionSale)) { HeaderText = HeaderLine };
      engine.WriteFile(filePath, concessionSaleList);
      return DateTime.Now;
    }

//-----MerchandiseSale.csv
public DateTime ExportResultsToCsv(string filePath, string HeaderLine, List<MerchandiseSale> merchandiseSaleList)
  {
     engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(MerchandiseSale)) { HeaderText = HeaderLine };
     engine.WriteFile(filePath, merchandiseSaleList);
     return DateTime.Now;
  }
```

While Googling, I read some concepts in `Generics` however I'm not able to get an idea.  My concern, it is possible to use `Generics` here.  Like having one generic method instead of many method like above.

Please shed some light on this issue.  Is it possible to reduce the number of methods?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any inheritance relationship between `RetailTransaction`, `ConcessionSale` and `MerchandiseSale`, such as all inherit from the same base class?

Comment: @KingKing No. There is no inheritance relationship between these on class.

Comment: @user1671639 Then you should add something. For example an interface `IExportableToCsv` or something. The `FileHelperEngine` probably has some restrictions on the type you pass anyway.

Comment: @poke I'm not using interface here.  Where the `FileHelperEngine` is the default class to invoke `FileHelper`.  Is there a better way to do it.  Please correct me, if I meant something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public DateTime ExportResultsToCsv<T>(string filePath, string HeaderLine, List<T> data)   
{
    engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(T)) { HeaderText = HeaderLine };
    engine.WriteFile(filePath, data);
    return DateTime.Now;   
}
```

For more info on generics [see this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Comment: +1 thank you so much.  I took long time to reply since reading about Generics.  I will check this once I get back on monday.

Answer (score 2):

This is a situation where you can use generics. You would use a type variable, usually T is used so that is why you commonly see it. This variable will replace the type of your list. As a result, you will need to pass the list type when calling the method

```
public DateTime ExportResultsToCsv<T>(string filePath, string HeaderLine, List<T> SaleList)
{
 engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(T)) { HeaderText = HeaderLine };
 engine.WriteFile(filePath, SaleList);
 return DateTime.Now;
}
```

and then you could simply call it like this:

```
ExportResultsToCsv(filePath,Header,salesList)
```

Comment: I don't think the `<...>` should be clearly specified because it will be inferred from the parameter type. So `ExportResultsToCsv(filePath,Header,salesList)` is enough.

Comment: @KingKing - That would give you a compiler error, "The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found". However, you can omit the type when calling the method. I thought you were talking about the signature of the method, I can make it less verbose.

Comment: Of course I talked about the 2 **last lines of code** you posted above. I'm not a newbie in generics stuff.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much.  Only one thing is balance, I have to test this.  Can you please share some basic tutorials/ examples to get hands dirty in Generics?

Comment: @user1671639 - Check out the examples at the MSDN. The remarks section can be instructive as well. [Generics - C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t(v=vs.90).aspx) is a great place to start. Lots of information and examples. Make sure to look at all of the related  sections linked.