# Errors on applying Generics methods

Tags: c#, generics

With reference to my [**previous question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551104/how-to-apply-generics-methods), I have tuned my code to use **`Generics`** like

```
FileHelperEngine engine;
public DateTime ExportResultsToCsv<T>(string filePath, string HeaderLine, List<T> data)   
{
    engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(T)) { HeaderText = HeaderLine };
    engine.WriteFile(filePath, data);
    return DateTime.Now;   
}
```

However when I tried to integrate it in my code, I'm facing the following 2 errors:

> **Error   1** The best overloaded method match for
>   'FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine<object>.WriteFile(string,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>)' has some invalid
>   arguments
>
> **Error   2** Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>'

I couldn't get what the error is about.  Can someone help on this.

**Error line :**

```
engine.WriteFile(filePath, data);
```

**Updates1:**

I'm using **`FileHelper.dll`** for Csv file conversion and **`FileHelperEngine`** is class belongs to that dll.

**Updates2:**
As @sza suggested, I changed and following is the screenshot of my error

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the signature of `WriteFile`?

Comment: @KingKing I can't understand signature.  `WriteFile` is the predefined method of `FileHelper.dll`.

Comment: The two error messages are you telling you that the second argument of `WriteFile` expects a `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`, and you're trying to pass in a `System.Collections.Generic.List`.  You need to pass in an object that implements IEnumerable.

Comment: @Tim It was working before I was applying `Generics`.  If possible please check my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551104/how-to-apply-generics-methods

Comment: @Tim doesn't `List` implements `IEnumerable`?

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly - It does; but the error message (if I read it correctly) seems to imply that it doesn't.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens When I added `using System.LINQ;`.  I ended with a warning `Warning 1 The using directive for 'System.Linq' appeared previously in this namespace`and the same 2 error.

Comment: How about change `engine.WriteFile(filePath, data);` to `engine.WriteFile(filePath, data.ToList());`

Comment: @sza - What benefit would calling `ToList()` on a List yield?

Comment: @sza I tried but still no improvement.  I have update this in my question.

Comment: What happens if you use `new FileHelperEngine(T)` instead of `typeof(T)`?  Just wondering since T is already a Type.

Comment: @Tim As you said, I changed `engine = new FileHelperEngine(T) { HeaderText = HeaderLine };` and the error is  `Error 1 'T' is a 'type parameter' but is used like a 'variable'`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is why. Let's take a look at the [source code](http://cedweb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CedWeb/FileHelpers/Engines/FileHelperEngine.cs)

```
        /// <include file='FileHelperEngine.docs.xml' path='doc/WriteFile/*'/>
#if ! GENERICS
        public void WriteFile(string fileName, IEnumerable records)
#else
        public void WriteFile(string fileName, IEnumerable<T> records)
#endif
        {
            WriteFile(fileName, records, -1);
        }
```

Since you are **not** using generic type of `FileHelperEngine` (the generic way is `FileHelperEngine<T>`), you can see the method takes the 2nd parameter as `IEnumerable`, which is **not** the generic `IEnumerable<T>` but a simple iteration over a non-generic collection.

So I believe you can do the following to make your code work:

```
engine.WriteFile(filePath, (IEnumerable)data);
```

or

```
engine.WriteFile(filePath, data as IEnumerable);
```

or

```
engine.WriteFile(filePath, data.Cast<Object>());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 Hats of to your effort.  However `engine.WriteFile(filePath, (IEnumerable)data);` and `engine.WriteFile(filePath, data as IEnumerable);` didn't worked.  whereas casting as an object works perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: @user1671639 thank you, I will take another look tmr, the first and 2nd casts should work I think

Comment: @user1671639 I'm fairly certain you can avoid the cast by simply changing the constructor you're using from `FileHelperEngine(typeof(T))` to `FileHelperEngine<T>()`.

Comment: @TiesonT. Yeah. Agreed. That's the easiest and leanest way.

Comment: @TiesonT. I  changed like `engine = new FileHelperEngine<T>() { HeaderText = HeaderLine };` as you mentioned.  But got an error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine<T>' to 'FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine'`  Please correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: @user1671639 That's because you previously declared `engine` to be a `FileHelperEngine`. Unless you explicitly need to reference `engine` again outside of this method, move its declaration inside the method and change its declared type to either `var` or `FileHelperEngine<T>`, as shown in Dmitry Dovgopoly's answer.

Comment: @TiesonT. I did as you suggested.  But no success.  Please check these screenshots  http://s23.postimg.org/j6q0ip2wr/22111111111.png and http://s12.postimg.org/pms6swmb1/21111111111111111111111.png I'm really interested in learning Generics.  So please bear my newbie questions.

Comment: @user1671639 The second one is almost correct; the first line in the method should read `var engine = new FileHelperEngine<T>() { // the rest of your code... };`. I'd advise checking this out if you're not familiar with `var`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx

Answer (score 2):

try `FileHelperEngine<T>` instead of `FileHelperEngine`

```
public DateTime ExportResultsToCsv<T>(string filePath, string HeaderLine, List<T> data)  where T : class    
{
    FileHelperEngine<T> engine = new FileHelperEngine<T>() { HeaderText = HeaderLine };
    engine.WriteFile(filePath, data);
    return DateTime.Now;   
}

[FixedLengthRecord]
public class Foo
{

}
```

and using:

```
ExportResultsToCsv<Foo>("", new List<Foo>());
```

Comment: There is no `FileHelperEngine<T>` constructor - http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/FileHelpers.FileHelperEngineConstructor.html

Comment: Give a few minutes, I will try this method.

Comment: @Tim it actually does but there is no docimentation, chttp://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/generics.html

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly  Ah..ok.  Gotta love undocumented features in third party DLLs :)

Comment: What is `T` in the actual call to `ExportResultsToCsv` at the last line?

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly This also works.  Thank you so much.  But here I didn't apply `[FixedLengthRecord]
public class Foo
{

}`

Comment: @user1671639 i am not sure about the attribute. I had an error without it, so i mention it.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the generic tags in your question, and it now becomes apparent that you're trying to call `WriteFile` with an invalid type. Try casting your objects to, well, Object.

```
engine.WriteFile(filePath, data.Cast<Object>());
```

The problem occurs because `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IEnumerable<Object>` which the method expects.

Comment: Since everything derives from `Object`, wouldn't T be an Object?

Comment: @user1671639 it's very strange that the last method you used (without generics) works? If the `WriteFile` needs the second parameter to be `IEnumerable<object>`, you have to cast the second argument any way (using generics or not).

Comment: @KingKing (and Tim) the non-generic method works, because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant. It will implicitly cast `T` to `Object`, but that only works if `T` is a reference type - which it is in the original, non-generic method. The *generic* version of the method doesn't make that guarantee (i.e. with `where T: class`), so covariance won't work.

Comment: @JimmiTh Why do you mention `IEnumerable<T>` in a **non-generic** method? As I know, the signature of `WriteFile` requires the second argument to be `IEnumerable<object>` but as in the previous question, the OP passed in `List<RetailTransaction>`? How could it work?

Comment: Because `IEnumerable<T>` is used whether the method is generic or not. `List<RetailTransaction>` implements `IEnumerable<RetailTransaction>` which is assignable to `IEnumerable<object>` because of covariance. `List<T>` in the new, generic method isn't assignable, because `T` isn't guaranteed to be a reference type, and variance only works for reference types. If you added `where T: class` to the method signature, the generic version *should* work as written in the question.

Comment: @JimmiTh do you mean you can assign an `IEnumerable<RetailTransaction>` to an `IEnumerable<object>`? The answer is NO, you can't, I've tried assigning an `IEnumerable<Button>` to an `IEnumerable<object>`. You should try a demo yourself, I hope you do that right now and see it in action than just **guess**.

Comment: I hope you use less condescending language in other comments... Guess what? I *already* tried it (even if I didn't need to, because it follows from how C# 4+ works). And the answer is YES, you can. http://pastebin.com/k9M19Yyn - compiles fine, runs fine - as well it should.

Comment: @JimmiTh You should have mentioned the version of .NET before, the test I made was in .NET 3.5, it's interesting that it works for .NET 4+. If so just appending `where T : class` on the generic method without using `.Cast<object>` is the solution for the OP.